# How to automatically convert blank lines to something else

Tags: macros, spacing, line-breaking

I want to convert blank lines to `\\[0.2cm]` automatically

```
TextText
Text

TextTextText
TextTextText
Text

Text
```

is what i copy paste inside the document
but i do not want any indent and a specific gap after each "Text" but not for each line
and it should have the properties like this

```
TextText
Text
\\[0.2cm]
TextTextText
TextTextText
Text
\\[0.2cm]
Text
```

i presume it works with a macro but i could not find anything that works with blank lines

Comment: Welcome! Blank lines are just new paragraphs, so you need to set the parameter `parskip` to whatever value you want.

Comment: Keep the empty lines and add `\usepackage{parskip}`.

Comment: parskip did not work since each line got a wider gap and not only after the Text
The Text is more than one line long 
so i wanna avoid the gaps inside the Text

Comment: Use line breaks instead of paragraphs breaks is the wrong way.  Without using any package, you can set `\parindent` to `0pt` and  `\parskip` to an invariable length (e.g.  `\setlength\parskip{0.2cm}`) instead of to a stretchable and shrinkable glue as `1cm plus 1fil minus 2mm`  that could have sense to  produce variable skips to fill better the pages, but with only  2-3 small paragraphs in a page will produce (obviously) *huge* gaps. Without a real document (minimal but working example) is hard to say more since other glues can also play a role.

Comment: [This is how it looks with parskip](https://i.imgur.com/Zs6161k.png)
[This is how its suppose to look](https://i.imgur.com/fUgIcix.png)
It is more denser/compact
thanks anyways how do i close this question?

Comment: TeX takes the input-file/.tex-file for a set of instructions for appending tokens to the token-stream These tokens are then "digested" by TeX (mouth: expansion, stomach: executing assignments such as denoted by `\newcommand`, ...). When TeX in the .tex-input file encounters an empty line, it usually will insert the control-word-token `\par` into the token stream, no matter how `\par` is defined. Therefore an option might be to have the things where blank lines are to be `\\[0.2cm]` within a group/local scope wherein `\par` locally is redefined to expand to `\\[0.2cm]`.